# Observer pour désigner "Accomplir, suivre ce qui est prescrit par une loi, par une règle"

Tags: usage, synonymes

De nos jours, peut-on utiliser observer (ou sa forme pronominal s'observer) pour

> Accomplir, suivre ce qui est prescrit par une loi, par une règle

comme par exemple dans

> C'est la loi loi de l'action et de la réaction qui s'observe lorsque qu'un aimant et un morceau de fer de même masse se font face.

Est-ce alors, dans ce contexte, antonyme de *transgresser/viole/enfreindre une loi* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans l'exemple choisi « s'observe » ne signifie pas « se conforme » mais  « est vérifiée », est reconnue », « est constatée ».

Dans le sens de « se conformer », « obéir », « suivre ce qui est prescrit », le verbe *n'est jamais pronominal*.

- Observer le règlement est une nécessité, même pour les gendarmes !
- Ils observent les règles parce que ça leur coute moins cher.

Le verbe non construit avec « se », selon le contexte, est un antonyme de « transgresser/violer/enfreindre » (une loi/un principe/un engagement/…).

Dans le sens de  «  vérifier », «  constater », « voir », il n'est pas strictement pronominal non plus. Il y a deux syntaxes équivalentes (même sens).

- (*voix active*) On observe la loi la plus élémentaire de l'électricité en frottant deux corps l'un contre l'autre.
- (*emploi pronominal à sens passif*) La loi la plus élémentaire de l'électricité s'observe en frottant deux corps l'un contre l'autre.

Voir [TLFi C 1.](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/observer).

On peut utiliser de façon entièrement équivalente les trois syntaxes suivantes.

- C'est la loi de l'action et de la réaction qui **s'observe** lorsque qu'un aimant et un morceau de fer de même masse se font face.
- C'est la loi de l'action et de la réaction que **l'on observe** lorsque qu'un aimant et un morceau de fer de même masse se font face.
- C'est la loi de l'action et de la réaction qui **est observée** lorsque qu'un aimant et un morceau de fer de même masse se font face.

Answer (score 2):

Votre phrase est incorrecte parce que vous inversez le processus de réflexion. Le verbe approprié est *appliquer*.

c.f. méthode scientifique (expérimentale).